# Passing enum to function not working

Tags: javascript, enums

I'm trying to pass an enum to a function, but keep getting an 'undefined' error.

If I try this:

```
var myVar = new myFunc('{ first:1, second:2 }')
```

and then

```
    function myFunc(enum) {
    var myEnum = enum;
    }
```

I find that `myEnum` is defined as `{ first:1, second:2 }`
but `myEnum.second` is undefined.

If I hard-code the same values directly into the `myEnum =` it works.

I also tried putting the braces on the `myEnum =`  line instead, but no change.

What am I doing wrong? Have I simply passed a string to `myEnum`?

If so, how can I ensure that `myEnum` is indeed an enum?

Comment: You are passing a **string** to the function. Strings don't have `second` property. Pass an **object** instead: `myFunc({ first:1, second:2 })`. You can learn more about objects in http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html . (JavaScript doesn't have "enums").

Comment: `enum` is a reserved word in javascript.

Comment: While I suspect you are just toying around with this, it should be noted that using `new` with a function is specifically for creating object instances. If you just need a static object that holds enums, just write: `var myEnums = { first:1, second:2 }` and you can still pass `myEnums` anywhere else you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you are using string as you have bounded the object inside quotes '

`var myVar = new myFunc('{ first:1, second:2 }')`

`myEnum.second` means you are trying to access the the `second` property of the `myEnum` referrenced object, which is not, as you have used quotes `'` around

use

```
var myVar = new myFunc({ first:1, second:2 })
```

Comment: Visitors will be able to learn more if you *explain* your solution and the problem the OP has. Please explain which changes you made and why you made them.

Comment: sure i will, just a matter of rapidity to give answer